# Creating a line in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have a table with 2 pairs of coordinates and I would like to create a line that connects these coordinates to show their connection.

x1, y1 must connect to x2,y2.

I have read about `St_MakeLine` but I can't find any queries that show an example with data in the same table.

Comment: On the ST_MakeLine documentation, you have several examples that can help you. Some queries combine ST_MakeLine with 2 ST_MakePoint. It can work for you.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see an example of using data from two separate columns. I have over 35000 coordinates in each column.

Comment: SELECT ST_AsText( ST_MakeLine(ST_MakePoint(1,2), ST_MakePoint(3,4)) ); wouldn't work in this case only if I could include the column names in the brackets

Comment: In the examples, the values entered in the parameters of the ```ST_MakePoint``` function are numerical values, you can specify the name of a column instead of the numerical value directly.

Comment: Thanks.... The result of this query is a linestring with some random alphanumeric sequence SELECT ST_AsText( ST_MakeLine(ST_MakePoint(hh_x,hh_y), ST_MakePoint(gp_x,gp_y)) )
FROM house_hold_final   can I edit this to create a new table in the database

Comment: I need the line output to have a geom column so I can calculate the length of each line

Comment: Add a geometry column and update it by your select request

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the SQL queries as yet... Is it possible for you to show me an example

Comment: You can try my request of the @ThingumaBob request

Comment: Also, a late welcome to [GIS.SE]! I strongly recommend to take the [tour] to get familiar with our standards towards a 'good question', and how to reward answers!

Answer (score 1):

Execute the following request by replacing the parameters.

```
# Duplication of your table 
CREATE TABLE house_hold_final_bis AS SELECT * FROM house_fold_final ;

# Drop the Geometry Column (replace with the name of your geometry)
SELECT DropGeometryColumn('house_hold_final_bis','geometry') ; 

# Add a geometry column
SELECT AddGeometryColumn('house_hold_final_bis', 'geometry', 4326, 'LINESTRING', 2) ; 

# Update the geometry with your request 
UPDATE house_fold_final_bis 
SET geometry = ST_AsText( ST_MakeLine(ST_MakePoint(hh_x,hh_y), ST_MakePoint(gp_x,gp_y)) )
```

Tell me if it works.

Comment: This didn't work..... The house_hold_final table already has a geom column.... what I would need is a new table that contains the line between hh_x, hh_y and gp_x, gp_y with a geom column

Comment: @WalterRossWilliams I edited my post

Answer (score 1):

To create a new table:

```
CREATE TABLE house_hold_final_geometry AS
  SELECT <id_column>,
         ST_SetSRID(ST_MakeLine(ST_MakePoint(hh_x, hh_y), ST_MakePoint(gp_x, gp_y)), <SRID>)::GEOMETRY(LINESTRING, <SRID>) AS geom
  FROM  house_hold_final
  ORDER BY
          <id_column>
;

CREATE INDEX ON house_hold_final_geometry
  USING GIST(geom)
;
```

To add a geometry column `geom` to your initial table:

```
ALTER TABLE house_hold_final
  ADD COLUMN geom GEOMETRY(LINESTRING, <SRID>)
;

UPDATE house_hold_final
  SET geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakeLine(ST_MakePoint(hh_x, hh_y), ST_MakePoint(gp_x, gp_y)), <SRID>)
;

CREATE INDEX ON house_hold_final
  USING GIST(geom)
;
```

---

Run

```
VACUUM ANALYZE house_hold_final[_geometry];
```

afterwards to update table statistics.

Comment: Thanks, the first query created a new table with the geom column and the preview of the data looks fine. Now I need to calculate the length of each line and insert that in the new table.

Comment: the final query looked like this CREATE TABLE gp_sl AS
  SELECT gid,
         ST_SetSRID(ST_MakeLine(ST_MakePoint(hh_x, hh_y), ST_MakePoint(gp_x, gp_y)), 29902)::GEOMETRY(LINESTRING, 29902) AS geom
  FROM  house_hold_final
  ORDER BY
          gid
;
CREATE INDEX ON gp_sl
  USING GIST(geom)

Comment: Just add a column (type `DOUBLE PRECISION`) and `UPDATE <table> SET <column> = ST_Length(geom)`.